# How to increase the limit size of body's message PHP Stomp

Tags: php, stomp

My question is in the title...

It work's well when I send a message, but when I read this message with `stomp->readFrame()` , Stomp return me `false`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

after creating connection you have to subscribe the queue also.

and for send the message you can connect and sent message.

follow thees step for read frame:

```
$link = stomp_connect('ssl://localhost:61612');
 stomp_subscribe($link, '/queue/foo');
 $frame = stomp_read_frame($link);
 stomp_close($link);
```

I think it may help you.

Comment: That's not helpful but thanks. My problem is when a message is larger than 1024 bytes, stomp return false.